# Why does my ASUS VivoBook 14 have performance issues when on battery?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, battery, gpu

I bought a new ASUS VivoBook 14. My laptop has the following specs:
CPU: install i5 CPU (1.6GHz * 8 ~ 1.8 GHz)
Integrated GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 (2GB Shared)
Render GPU: NVIDIA Geforce MX250 (2GB Dedicated, 2GB Shared)
Memory 4GB (Upgradable)

[image: CPU reads of two different utilities]
I don't know why I'm experiencing performance spikes when performing heavy tasks or playing a game on battery. Although a third party utility reads it differently, it is clear that I'm experiencing what the built-in task manager says above.

I tried looking on various settings that involve performance and battery life just to fix the problem but it seems that is not the case here.

[image: Battery saving mode disabled on battery window.]
Battery saving mode disabled on battery window.

[image: Power plan settings page 1][image: Power plan settings page 2]
I even got to the current power plan configuration.

[image: NCIDIA Graphics Control Panel]
Games use the render-only GPU by default so I thought this is the case but...nope. Still happening.

[image: Intel Graphics Control Panel]
I then also thought that Intel Graphics might be affecting it since it is the Display GPU but still happening.

Is there something that I am missing or it is the actual problem of the hardware itself? What causes it to have that kind of behavior? I know that this is not meant for gaming but come on. Even playing minecraft with very low settings it still happen? Even editing videos with Resolve is a hassle. Using optimized media feature is not an effective resort.

Update: I tried cooling it down for a long time then playing a game. It still happens. I've also observed that other programs are performing great without using GPU. So I assume that the GPU is the case. It is configured to run in maximum performance.

Comment: Thermal throttling sounds likely. What are your CPU and GPU temperatures during these spikes? Note that for devices where the battery is close to the CPU that charging can cause extra heat and so throttle more, once the battery is fully charged it will stop contributing to the heat.

Comment: I can't tell the temperature exactly. Since you have mentioned that, I will go to test my laptop again with low temperature.

Comment: A program such as HWInfo should be able to show you realtime temperatures.

Comment: Check Power Options in control panel for while on battery.